# Port forwarding from modem to a subnet

Tags: router, port-forwarding, subnet

I have a webcam server that requires port forwarding to be able to access it from Internet, but the webcam server is located in a subnet and I couldn't make it work.

Description of my setup:

1. There is a D-LINK ADSL modem router accessing Internet, its IP address of 192.168.1.1.
2. This modem only has one output ethernet port. Currently a Ethernet cable connects this port to switch (not router, switch), a few PCs in my house connects to this switch via ethernet cable. They all have IP address of 192.168.1.x
3. I have a D-LINK wifi router placed at the center of the house, it has Ethernet connection to the switch, it's IP address is 192.168.1.2
4. Now anything connected to this wifi router, will have IP address of 192.168.0.x, where 192.168.0.1 is the IP of the wifi router.
5. Now the problem is, I have a webcam server connected to this wifi router via Ethernet, it has IP of 192.168.0.50.
6. I need to enable port forward from modem to this webcam server. Since i cant directly port flrward from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.0.50, In my modem setup, I try to port forward to 192.168.1.2, and then on the wifi router, I try to port forward to 192.168.0.50.

Hoever this doesn't work so far. Any guides. On how can I setup this?

Screenshots of my modem router setup, I try to port forward to my Wifi router at 192.168.1.2:

[image: D-Link ADSL Modem Router setup a.]

[image: D-Link ADSL Modem Router setup b.]

Screenshots of my wifi router setup, I try to port forward to my webcam server at 192.168.0.50:

[image: D-LINK WIFI Router setup]

Comment: Generally speaking this site is only for non-home related questions (i.e. professional / at work)  But I can tell you, you probably need a router or at least route statements in your routers to route traffic from the 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.0.0/24 networks to each other.

Comment: Try to access 192.168.1.2 from one of PCs in the 192.168.1.x network and test whether you can reach the camera — this way you will test port forwarding in your wifi router without involving the modem.

Comment: @Snellgrove what do you mean by router statements? Any further guides? I am not expert in this, i am using Dlink. Thanks!

Comment: @SergeyVlasov in my current setup, I noticed that my PC at 192.168.1.x cannot reach anything in the zone of 192.168.0.x. I cant access 192.168.0.1 for the wifi router admin page and cant access 192.168.0.x for the camera server either...thanks for the tips. So I guess I need to do something to make this work, still figuring out what to configure...

Comment: You should not be able to reach 192.168.0.x addresses from 192.168.1.x directly, because your wifi router performs NAT, so the only reachable address will be the WAN address of your wifi router, and its LAN addresses could be accessed only as defined in port forwarding rules (there might be also a DMZ option, which basically forwards all ports to the specified LAN IP).

Comment: Let me guess, you connected the D-Link's **WAN** port to your **LAN**, right? That's a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off dhcpd on your router and let the adsl modem to allocate ips.

Comment: Yep. Connect the router LAN-to-LAN, not LAN-to-WAN.

Answer (score 0):

My guess that your router is blocking non routable IP addresses (192.168.1.x in your example) coming from it's WAN interface. Possible solutions:

1. I don't know brand/firware of your router, but you could check if it
   has the option to allow to forward non routable IPs.
2. Don't use separate sub-net. Use it like this:

   WAN -> router -> switch > your home network

Comment: Hi I would like to know how to "forward non router IPs", my modem is DLINK, wifi router is dlink too.

Comment: Your wifi router may not have these options available. Just use it as access point, the manual should explain how to accomplish this.